# Entity Framework 6 and applying migration to remote database

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I'm new to EF 6 and struggling how to easily apply migrations to the "remote" database.  My local database is SQL Server Express and my remote database is SQL Server at GoDaddy.  When I apply migrations and update the database, it appears to use the connection string from my web.config.  The way I was able to apply the migration to my remote database was to swap the connection strings from my Web.Release.config and web.config files and then perform an Update-Database -TargetMigration {name of the migration}.

Are there any commands that I can use to target a specific database (without swapping the connection strings)?  I've used get-help update-database but can't seem to find what I'm looking for.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply command line switch.

`Update-Database [-SourceMigration <String>] [-TargetMigration <String>] [-Script] [-Force] 
  [-ProjectName <String>] [-StartUpProjectName <String>] [-ConfigurationTypeName <String>] 
  -ConnectionString <String> -ConnectionProviderName <String> 
  [-AppDomainBaseDirectory <String>] [<CommonParameters>]`

[EF Migrations Command Reference](https://coding.abel.nu/2012/03/ef-migrations-command-reference/#Update-Database)

Comment: Thank you.  That link was helpful.  I was missing the ConnectionStringName  parameter.  I ended up adding a GoDaddy connection string to my web.config file so that I have both connection strings in the same file.

Comment: @DrZ: You can also use just -ConnectionString to avoid having production connection string in the source code/web.config.